# Find all numeric columns in a table?

Tags: sql, database

How do I find all the numeric columns in a table without referencing the column names explicitly? I'm iterating over bunch of table names and query each with snowflake sql (using jinja for looping inside the sql statement). I try to use something like this:

```
{% for table in table_list %}
SELECT * 
FROM FEATURE_SET_{{ table }}
WHERE ISNUMERIC(?)
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to populate `WHERE` clause since I don't make a reference to any column. The table list has bunch of different tables, some tables has numeric columns, some don't, all the tables are different in shape, having different amount of columns, and etc. Any idea on how to accomplish this goal?

Comment: Why? Use the system tables and check the data type.  Keep in mind each RDBMS keeps a catalog of tables, indexes, columns datatypes, orders etc within the system to know whats where.  you can access this information with the proper permissions.  so you could just query these tables to get what you're after.  No loops.. However: without knowing the database and version not sure how to direct you to the appropriate tables.  for example: Oracle... ALL_TAB_COLS.  Google your RDBMS ALL_TAB_COLS equivalent

Comment: I will compute aggregates on numeric columns, that's why i wanted to such columns first. This is the first step of my end goal... @xQbert

Comment: So then procedure it. and use dynamic SQL.  get all your numeric columns from system tables then loop through that writing your dynamic SQL and execute it to get your aggregates.  Caution though: this could be very intensive depending on table size and volumne of "NUMERIC" records/columns

Comment: Also, you know the table you're iterating through so you could use List_AGG and dynamically generate your where clause using the system table and table name and an "in" caluse... `where COLUMN_NAME in (SELECT * FROM SYSTABLE WHERE TYPE=NUMERIC and TABLE_NAME = loopvalue')` ... something similar... but maybe I'm not following yet.

Comment: this SQL query is going to be used in a task within an Airflow dag, so I need a single query instead of a procedure. Your suggestion can probably be done but I'm not that experienced enough both on databases and Airflow. So I'd appreciate if you can give me hints on modifying the above sample SQL :) @xQbert

Comment: Basisically I'm suggesting using a subquery in your where clause to get the columnns which are numeric using the system tables based on your known table Name so... where column in ( `SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM ALL_TAB_COLS WHERE TABLE_NAME = @VARIABLE and DATA_TYPE='NUMBER')`)  but again, I don't fully undersand the problem, nor airflow,

Comment: oh okay, I see what you're saying now. Sure, will give it a try. Thanks!!! @xQbert

Comment: i did what you said but i still don't have a reference for the ```column``` in where clause

Comment: this has to be dynamic SQL in order to work.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you can use this query to find numeric columns:

```
SELECT t.name AS [table],
       c.name AS column_name,
       TYPE_NAME(user_type_id) AS data_type
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t
ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE TYPE_NAME(user_type_id) IN
    (
        'bigint', 'int', 
        'smallint', 'tinyint', 'decimal', 'numeric',
        'smallmoney', 'money', 'bit', 'float', 'real'
    )
AND t.name = 'Your table name'
```

Replace your table name in the last line.